# Processes Defined by Realizable Higher-Order Operators

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $X_t$ is a (continuous) diffusion process solving
$$
dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t
,
$$ then its infinitesimal generator, denoted by $L$ is of the form by
$$
L(f) =
b(x) \cdot \nabla_{x} f(x) + \frac1{2} \big( \sigma(x) \sigma(x)^{\top} \big) : \nabla_{x} \nabla_{x} f(x).
$$
Thus, $L$ is a second-order differential operator.

### Question

If $X_t$ is a *stochastic process* (not a diffusion), which admits an infinitesimal generator $L$, is it possible for $L$ to be of order greater than $2$?

Comment: I suppose the answer is "no", but for a definite answer one needs to know precisely what do we mean by a "stochastic process" and "infinitesimal generator". If $X_t$ is supposed to be Markovian and the infinitesimal generator is to be a local operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is necessarily a second-order operator. On the other hand, in "rough" spaces (like fractals or percolation clusters) diffusions usually have higher-order operators as generators, although it is not clear whether one would still call them "differential operators".

Comment: I was thinking of a rough setting, would you happen to have a reference for this case?

Comment: I am not an expect here, but there is a number of survey works with "Diffusions on fractals"  or similar phrases in their titles, these should be a good entry point into the literature. For example, by [Barlow](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~barlow/preprints/stfr.pdf), [Strichartz](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=069112731X), [Kumagai](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kumagai/ICM-Proc-TK-new.pdf), [Kumagai](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=331903152X). Disclaimer: I just found some of these on the web, I did not even look into them.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a notion of infinitesimal generator for non-markovian processes which can achieve this?

Comment: I do not know, although I very much doubt. Probabilistic constructions typically lead to positivity-preserving operators, while higher-order operators generate semigroups that do not preserve positivity. That said, you may like the paper by [Allouba and Zheng](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1015345772) from Ann. Probab. 29(4) (2001), where they link a very weird non-Markovian process to the bi-Laplacian. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This is good also, though I was expecting a connection to processes like fBM.

Comment: Did you try searching yourself? I was not aware of this connection, but one of the first Google hits is a paper by [Baudoin and Coutin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414906001347), which seems to be close to what you are asking for.